# Is the where clause necessary in content resolver update method?

Tags: java, android, uri

I looked on the documentation for the update method in content resolver. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update(android.net.Uri,android.content.ContentValues,java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])

and saw that update had a method signature of

```
public final int update (Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] selectionArgs)
```

If you specify the id in the uri, would you even need the where clause? Similar idea in delete method. Would the where and selectionArgs only be needed when you don't specify id, because id will get you a specific record?

Comment: it all depends on actual ContentProvider implementation